# Angular 2 - Get the value of changed FormControl in Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a simple Form built with `FormBuilder`:

```
this.contactForm = formBuilder.group({
  'name': [''],
  'email': [''],
  'phone': [''],
});
```

I want to watch every control for changes, and run a function with the updated value when this happens:

```
getContacts(value: any) {
    this.phoneContacts.findContact(value).then(
        contacts => {
            // do something
        }
    );
}
```

Right now, I'm doing this for every control, using `bind` to have access to the `this` object of the component:

```
this.contactForm.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(this.getContacts.bind(this));
this.contactForm.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(this.getContacts.bind(this));
this.contactForm.get('phone').valueChanges.subscribe(this.getContacts.bind(this));
```

Is there any way to watch for changes and have the updated value with just one subscription? I know I can subscribe directly to `this.contact.form`, but then instead of just the updated control I get all controls as the value.

Comment: So if I understand it right you want something like `this.contactForm.subscribeToUpdated()` ?

Comment: Exactly! Where `subscribetoUpdated()` will give me the value from the last changed input

Answer (score 6):

You can merge the 3 individual observables into one using the merge operator. That will give you a single observable that emits the single value any time any one of the form field values changes.

```
this.contactForm.get('name').valueChanges
    .merge(this.contactForm.get('email').valueChanges)
    .merge(this.contactForm.get('phone').valueChanges)
```

The main problem with the approach above is that you now don't know which value goes with which form control. One solution is to map the value changes into another object that contains both the value and the control (i.e. the source of the value)

```
// making some local variables for convenience
let name = this.contactForm.get('name')
let email = this.contactForm.get('email'
let phone = this.contactForm.get('phone')

name.valueChanges.map(v => ({control: name,value: v})
    .merge(email.valueChanges.map(v => ({control: email, value: v}))
    .merge(phone.valueChanges.map(v => ({control: phone, value: v}))
```

This will give an observable that emits whenever any of the fields change, and the value it emits will be an object containing the value and the control that emitted that value.

Answer (score 0):

You may use valueChanges for single control and subscribe to it :

```
 this.contactForm.controls['name'].valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(" name : " + value)
})
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but I don't want to do it separately for every `FormControl`

Comment: OK so you a proper RxJs operator and merge all Observables into one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all controls valueChanges observable from the form and merge all the stream:

```
const observablesArray = this.contactFrom.controls.map((control) => control.valueChanges);

Observable.merge(...observablesArray).do(console.log).subscribe();
```

Now you receive a value and not an object with all the fields when the field change.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Could you create a StackBlitz? This would be the answer and quite useful!

Answer (score -1):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.contactForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value.name)  
    });
}
```

OR

you can target individual control like this,

```
this.contactForm.controls.name.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
     console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Inside the subscription, I run a function that takes the updated value and does something with it. Therefore, I need to know which `FormControl` was updated. It can be either one of them

Comment: Your updated answer is what I'm already doing right now, except that I have to do it three times. What I'm interested in is if I can make just one subscription, to the entire `FormGroup`, and get only the `FormControl` that was updated

Comment: I don't know what could be an exact answer but you can opt for a workaround.

Comment: Yes you can. You can use my answer with merging but you need to somehow mark the controls to identify them. For example you can use objects as values and inject some control id to this object.