# NG2 form valueChanges : how do i find out which element changed?

Tags: angular

i have code like this...

```
this.form.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(500)
            .subscribe(data => doSomething(data));
```

how can I find out which of the form elements caused the change?
I could add individual valueChanges listeners to every element as its created but that doesn't seem right. is there some way to get access to underlying event object?

Comment: Maybe this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39977343